# proper way to get the last element of the array when split is used on the string within JSON

Tags: arrays, string, typescript

I have a JSON response from the server and I am using `map` to use only necessary `key:value`pairs in Angular (typescript) that will be used to display on the Frontend side.

here `bizStep` is actually according to a standard (EPCIS) and has the following value:

```
urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:receiving
```

I only want to the user to read `receiving` hence I used `split` and obtained the last value of the array to display the value.

The logic is shown below:

```
this.serv.getEpcisInfo(code) // HTTP GET Service from Angular
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res.map(el => { // map only some key value pairs now!
      return {
           'business step': el.bizStep.split(':')[el.bizStep.split(':').length - 1]
    });
  });
```

But it is observed that in order to obtain the overall `length` of the splited string array I have to write the expression `el.bizStep.split(':')` twice.

Is there a shorthand or elegant expression to obtain the last string value of the array.

I did try to use `el.bizStep.split(':')[-1]` however this expression failed and did not provide me any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.pop` since you don't need to preserve the result of the split, i.e. `el.bizStep.split(':').pop()`.

A more general approach would be to use an anonymous function, e.g.:

`(s => s[s.length-1])(el.bizStep.split(':'))`

You could modify this to get elements other than the last.  Of course, this example has no error checking on the length or type of `el.bizStep`.

Comment: this makes sense in my case where I am using only the last element. But in general I still have to write the complete expression in order to get, for example, the second last element right?

Comment: Updated with an alternative for those cases.